# Rails set show action rooting as post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my rails app i have such route for carts controller:

```
resources :carts
```

so in layout, according to my logic i have:

```
= link_to "Моя корзина", @cart
```

and in browser i see for example:

```
******:3000/carts/112
```

Could i however do nested rails route show as post-like request? so i will have:

```
******:3000/carts/
```

also rake routes:

```
arts GET    /carts(.:format)                                                          carts#index
                                  POST   /carts(.:format)                                                          carts#create
                         new_cart GET    /carts/new(.:format)                                                      carts#new
                        edit_cart GET    /carts/:id/edit(.:format)                                                 carts#edit
                             cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format)                                                      carts#show
                                  PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)                                                      carts#update
                                  DELETE /carts/:id(.:format)                                                      carts#destroy
                             cart POST   /carts/:id(.:format)                                                      carts#show
```

I now how to write it for my own methods... But how to be with build-in show?

**i need to change show route, so that id for show is sending not as get-param by url, but as post-param in request...**

Comment: Why do you want `show` to be via `POST`?  That's breaking RESTful conventions.  If you want a `POST` use `create` or `update`.

Comment: @nzifnab i need to hide cart id. this is first...

Comment: But...why?  if you're not updating the record on the server you shouldn't be sending it as a `POST`

Comment: if you want to hide the cart id from URL, doing a POST or PUT request is correct, but instead of using "show" method for that, have your own method (as I shown in my example), coz you should try to keep your controller RESTFull as much as possible

Comment: You've immediately stopped being RESTful the moment you perform a `GET` using HTTP `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resources` method simply puts in a bunch of predefined routes, as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Specifically, it is adding the equivalent of

```
get '/carts/:id' => 'carts_controller#show'
post '/carts' => 'carts_controller#create'
...
```

If you want to use a different set of routes, don't use `resources`, and just define your own routes instead.

Also, you can't hide the cart id from the user this way.  If the request contains the ID, it means that the user can see it.  He might have to view it with Firebug or by looking at the page source instead of his address bar, but it's still not secret or protected in any way.

Comment: i could add another route using match... but how with post there? like match "/cart" => "carts#show", :as => :blablabla.... but will this work?

Comment: but it's still not secret or protected in any way... i know it, but first step is to hide it from url

Comment: Sure it would work, as long as you place it before your `resources :carts` line (precedence in the routing).

Comment: @brabertaser even if you do it as a `POST` that id isn't a secret... What exactly are you trying to accomplish? o.O

Comment: i now this is not secret! but better is that anybody see this id in url: this is first!

Answer (score 2):

you could add routes like this (routes.rb)

Ex:

```
resources :carts do
  member do
    post :add
 end
end
```

[more about rails routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just run `rake routes` in your console and see the routes you have.

Also you can read more about RESTful routes at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: and? I need to change that route!

Comment: and? man give answer, i read that more times, but there is no solution for me!

Comment: What do you mean you need to change that route?  It automatically gives you a `show` action for that URL which is via GET AS WELL AS an `update` action to that URL which is via a `PUT`.  What are you asking for exactly?

Comment: @nzifnab i need to change show route, so that id for show is sending not as get-param by url, but as post-param in request...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want to do. Anyway it's a bad practice to change rails routing conception.

Comment: What's your use-case braber?  If you find yourself fighting rails in this manner you're probably not doing it right.